# Perl module dependency management

Tags: perl, dependencies

Scripts a.pl, b.pl and c.pl all live on machine x installed with perl v5.10.1 (i.e., just for examples sake). All three scripts use foo;, however they each need a different version of foo.pm:

a.pl - use foo .7;
b.pl - use foo 1.1;
c.pl - use foo 1.5;

If any of the three scripts does not use the exact version specified it will crash. Using some combination of CPAN modules describe your dependency management system that ensure each script uses the correct foo.pm version. Note, I have kept things simple, but in reality there could be many scripts each with unique version dependencies.

Comment: I don't suppose you can fix the scripts to all use the same version of Foo?  Otherwise you're just prolonging the maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 4):

[`only`](http://p3rl.org/only)